# Custom Annotation to validate request header in Spring

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot, annotations

**Set-up**

We have a set of microservices and we use Spring-cloud for service registry(Eureka) and API gateway(ZUUL). We are doing the authentication in ZUUL itself, once authenticated the ZUUL would add a request header with a value (say "Authenticated"). All the request to the core services comes through ZUUL so the authentication is done in ZUUL.

**Problem**

Each core services are running in different ports and if some request comes to the core services directly not through ZUUL then we wanted to check whether the request header contains "Authenticated".

1. If it contains "Authenticated" then the request should go through.
2. If it does not then the response should be 403

**Our Approach**

We are planning to create a **custom annotation** @validateAuthentication and check whether the request headers contains the "Authenticated" for each value. We do not want to add any spring security dependencies to the core services.

**Question**

1. Is our approach / design doable, can you please suggest how this can be done.
2. can you point me to some reference material to do this.
3. I already raised some question  [[Custom Annotation in Spring with BeanPostProcessor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39144736/custom-annotation-in-spring-with-beanpostprocessor]) on this subject, but could not proceed further.

If you need further details please let me know.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

We created a library which would process the custom annotation **@validateAuthentication**, we created Intercepter class extending **HandlerInterceptorAdapter**.

We implementing our validation of the request header in **preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler)** method.